# Find CDF of X and Y

Tags: probability-distributions

A group of five bonds are rated randomly where rating categories are 1,2,3.Let X and Y denote the minimum and maximum rating received by this group .Compute the CDF of X and Y

My efforts:

First PMF needs to be ascertained. Here ,I assume it is joint pmf . Now range of both $X$ and $Y$ is $\{1,2,3\}$. Probability of each bond(out of $5$) to get a rank $1,2,3$ is $1/3$. I am stucked in PMF table.

For example $X=1,Y=1$ ,what does it mean here?

Comment: I took the liberty to add your efforts to your question. This makes it more probable that people will help.

Comment: @drhab I'm not sure I'm overly comfortable with you presupposing the thoughts of the OP. How do we know (s)he has put any thought into the question at hand? Is this an appropriate edit?

Comment: @Kevin I admit that I have doubts myself too. It is the first (maybe last) time I did this. If in my view efforts must be added then usually I emphasize that these must show up in an edited question and not in a comment. This time I forgot that and a comment of the OP showed up. I took initiative, and pasted it in the question.

Comment: @drhab Ah, I did not see OP's comment, above, I thought these were *your* thoughts, my apologies. These efforts should have been down to the OP to paste in, I see why you did so. Thanks.

Comment: I couldnt understand the answer .  I thpught of Joint PMF table from which we cand find PMF and then CDF. Here K takes the value 1,2,3 FOR X is confusing

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**:

For maximum $Y$ we find $P(Y\leq k\}=\left(\frac{k}3\right)^5$ for $k=1,2,3$.

For minimum $X$ we find $P(X> k\}=\left(\frac{3-k}3\right)^5$ for $k=0,1,2$.

Do you understand why?

(Actually it was a wrong advice to first calculate the PMF, sorry).

Comment: Upvoted for a fine hint to the OP's question.